# Meanjs built in app, how to update USER array from articles module

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, meanjs

I'm using the Articles and Users implementation into [Meanjs](http://meanjs.org/) built-in app.

List of articles (View) with the button for every item:

```
<a data-ng-controller="MyArticlesController" data-ng-repeat="article in articles" class="list-group-item">
        <button data-ng-click="addArt2me()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus addArt2me" ></button>
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" data-ng-bind="article.title"></h4>
        <p> {{article.content | limitTo:140}} </p>
    </a>
```

And here the controller with the trigger function `$scope.addArt2me()`:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('users').controller('MyArticlesController', ['$scope', 'Articles', 'Users',    '$location',
function($scope, Articles, Users, $location) {

    var myUser = new Users($scope.user);

    $scope.addArt2me = function() {

        var myArticle = new Articles($scope.article);

        myUser.userArticles.push(myArticle._id);

        myUser.$update(function(response) {
            console.log("Actualize!! con : " + user.userArticles.length + "__" + response);
        }, function(errorResponse) {
            console.log("updatError: " + errorResponse);
            $scope.error = errorResponse;
        });

    }
}
]);
```

In the user's model I've an array of articles._id `userArticles`.

The View renders a list of articles with a button that triggers the function `addArt2me()` in the controller, which pushes and updates the myArticle._id inside ´userArticles´.

It works successfully and saves the element into DB :)

```
console: Actualize!! con : 60__[object Object]
```

...but only the first time, the next time it triggers an error :(

```
PUT http://localhost:3000/users 400 (Bad Request)
updatError: [object Object]´
```

Do I need to deal with some kind of service to update the USERS module being in ARTICLES module? 
Can't I just update the model of the user with Mongoose?
Why does it works well for the first saved article ?

Any guide is very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you add your backend controller's code?

Comment: Sure, please take a look [here](https://github.com/asael2/appnl/tree/master/app/models) Thanks!

Comment: Sorry those are the models, here the controllers https://github.com/asael2/appnl/tree/master/app/controllers

Comment: Where is $scope.user in the frontend? why don't you use this.user?

Answer (score 0):

I just founded, after 2 day of looking for it.

Needed to declare the User Model, outside the subcontroller because it iterates for every article.

so move ´$scope.myUser = new Users($scope.user);´ into ´ArticlesController´ Did the job!

Thanks for your time!